# Get the date an order was paid on Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can I get, on Woocommerce, the date an order had its status changed to paid/complete?

I saw something about getting the orders from a costumer, but this would be just the first step of my algorithm. Then I would need to know when it changed to complete.

The idea is to make a membership area: a payment lasts 3 months. So I will count the days passed since it was bought

Something related
https://www.skyverge.com/blog/get-all-woocommerce-orders-for-a-customer/

And this is what I use to know if a product was bought by the costumer

```
if (wc_customer_bought_product($customer_email, $user_id,$loop->post->ID)){
            $courses[] = $this->find($loop->post->ID);
          }
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you should look into:

> /mySite/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php

There is a __get function:

```
public function __get( $key ) {
        // Get values or default if not set.
        if ( 'completed_date' === $key ) {
            $value = ( $value = get_post_meta( $this->id, '_completed_date', true ) ) ? $value : $this->modified_date;
        } elseif ( 'user_id' === $key ) {
            $value = ( $value = get_post_meta( $this->id, '_customer_user', true ) ) ? absint( $value ) : '';
        } elseif ( 'status' === $key ) {
            $value = $this->get_status();
        } else {
            $value = get_post_meta( $this->id, '_' . $key, true );
        }

        return $value;
    }
```

So my understanding is that if you pass 'completed date' as the argument then it will return the completed_date.

It also gives you a hint where this date is i.e.

> get_post_meta

Well, at least that's where I would start.

Comment: you don't need to pass $key... use it like `$order->completed_date`, this will pass `completed_date` in `__get` as `$key`...

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WC_Order::completed_date()

Comment: You can't directly access properties on recent WooComm

Answer (score 3):

Probably the "most correct" way is:

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$date_obj = $order->get_date_paid();
echo $date_obj->date('d/m/Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

This should to the job on recente WP/WooCommerce.

```
$order = new WC_Order($sale_id);
echo $order->get_date_paid();
```